# Sample uniformly at random from an n-dimensional unit simplex

Tags: math, random, wolfram-mathematica

Sampling uniformly at random from an n-dimensional unit simplex is the fancy way to say that you want n random numbers such that

- they are all non-negative,
- they sum to one, and
- every possible vector of n non-negative numbers that sum to one are equally likely.

In the n=2 case you want to sample uniformly from the segment of the line x+y=1 (ie, y=1-x) that is in the positive quadrant.
In the n=3 case you're sampling from the triangle-shaped part of the plane x+y+z=1 that is in the positive octant of R3:

[image]

(Image from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex.)

Note that picking n uniform random numbers and then normalizing them so they sum to one does not work.  You end up with a bias towards less extreme numbers.

Similarly, picking n-1 uniform random numbers and then taking the nth to be one minus the sum of them also introduces bias.

Wikipedia gives two algorithms to do this correctly:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Random_sampling
(Though the second one currently claims to only be correct in practice, not in theory. I'm hoping to clean that up or clarify it when I understand this better. I initially stuck in a "WARNING: such-and-such paper claims the following is wrong" on that Wikipedia page and someone else turned it into the "works only in practice" caveat.)

Finally, the question:
What do you consider the best implementation of simplex sampling in Mathematica (preferably with empirical confirmation that it's correct)?

Related questions

- [Generating a probability distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171074/generating-a-probability-distribution)
- [java random percentages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007975/java-random-percentages)

Comment: It seems there are several methods that work fine - the only real differentiation is in speed and read-ability. What are your criterion other than 'best'?

Comment: Speed and readability are great criteria!  Conciseness could be another.  If you have an implementation that has anything at all going for it, go ahead and post it as an answer.

Comment: I think the Wikipedia warning is a little bogus;  the authors of the paper cited are worrying about perfect uniformity for a *discretized* version of this problem.  The 2nd algorithm described is perfectly correct from a mathematical point of view, and should work well in practice if you're prepared to regard 'random floating-point number from [0, 1]' as a good-enough approximation to 'random real number from [0, 1]'.

Comment: the link to sampling is dead

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/32618/2380).

Comment: Have you some intuitions about how to generalize the problem solution to the non-unit simplicies and maybe even convex polytopes?

Comment: There is [different approach][1], which requires only n-1 uniformely distributed values.


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/871220/54348

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This code can work:

```
samples[n_] := Differences[Join[{0}, Sort[RandomReal[Range[0, 1], n - 1]], {1}]]
```

Basically you just choose `n - 1` places on the interval `[0,1]` to split it up then take the size of each of the pieces using `Differences`.

A quick run of `Timing` on this shows that it's a little faster than Janus's first answer.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is pretty much isomorphic to the one I posted.  Thanks for the speed comparison, btw!

Comment: Oh, indeed it is! Somehow I thought that yours was different, but it looks the same now that I've taken another look.

Comment: Are there generalizations on non-unit simplexes or even (simplicial) convex polytopes?

Comment: @Orient Can't you just scale up the result to whatever size you want?

Comment: @BenAlpert I can simply scale the result up to, for the one hand, triangulation of desired convex polytope in accordance with hypervolumes of the produced simplices, but, on the other hand, I cannot simply deform the unit simplex into arbitrary simplex by means of only the linear transformations and hold the uniformity of spatial distributions by doing so.

Comment: I found [the solution](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/871220/54348) of general problem.

Comment: This is the method I came up with on my own, then I went online to search for something more efficient.  I found a great one on the Mathematica page, posted below.

Answer (score 9):

After a little digging around, I found [this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration.html) which gives a nice implementation of the Dirichlet Distribution.  From there it seems like it would be pretty simple to follow Wikipedia's method 1.  This seems like the best way to do it.

As a test:

```
In[14]:= RandomReal[DirichletDistribution[{1,1}],WorkingPrecision->25]
Out[14]= {0.8428995243540368880268079,0.1571004756459631119731921}
In[15]:= Total[%]
Out[15]= 1.000000000000000000000000
```

A plot of 100 samples:

[alt text http://www.public.iastate.edu/~zdavkeos/simplex-sample.png](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~zdavkeos/simplex-sample.png)

Answer (score 7):

I'm with zdav: the Dirichlet distribution seems to be the easiest way ahead, and the algorithm for sampling the Dirichlet distribution which zdav refers to is also presented on the Wikipedia page on the [Dirichlet distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Gamma_distribution).

Implementationwise, it is a bit of an overhead to do the full Dirichlet distribution first, as all you really need is `n` random `Gamma[1,1]` samples. Compare below
**Simple implementation**

```
SimplexSample[n_, opts:OptionsPattern[RandomReal]] :=
  (#/Total[#])& @ RandomReal[GammaDistribution[1,1],n,opts]
```

**Full Dirichlet implementation**

```
DirichletDistribution/:Random`DistributionVector[
 DirichletDistribution[alpha_?(VectorQ[#,Positive]&)],n_Integer,prec_?Positive]:=
    Block[{gammas}, gammas = 
        Map[RandomReal[GammaDistribution[#,1],n,WorkingPrecision->prec]&,alpha];
      Transpose[gammas]/Total[gammas]]

SimplexSample2[n_, opts:OptionsPattern[RandomReal]] := 
  (#/Total[#])& @ RandomReal[DirichletDistribution[ConstantArray[1,{n}]],opts]
```

**Timing**

```
Timing[Table[SimplexSample[10,WorkingPrecision-> 20],{10000}];]
Timing[Table[SimplexSample2[10,WorkingPrecision-> 20],{10000}];]
Out[159]= {1.30249,Null}
Out[160]= {3.52216,Null}
```

So the full Dirichlet is a factor of 3 slower. If you need m>1 samplepoints at a time, you could probably win further by doing `(#/Total[#]&)/@RandomReal[GammaDistribution[1,1],{m,n}]`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a nice concise implementation of the second algorithm from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Random_sampling):

```
SimplexSample[n_] := Rest@# - Most@# &[Sort@Join[{0,1}, RandomReal[{0,1}, n-1]]]
```

That's adapted from here: http://www.mofeel.net/1164-comp-soft-sys-math-mathematica/14968.aspx
(Originally it had Union instead of Sort@Join -- the latter is slightly faster.)

(See comments for some evidence that this is correct!)

Comment: I just ran a test, and it seems to work ok - the values are pretty uniform and all on the right line.  I'm not sure why it was downvoted.

Comment: The downvote was mine, and was accidental;  I apologise.  If you can make a trivial edit to your answer, I'll upvote.  This method looks correct to me.

Comment: I was just going to post this same method. On my machine it is eight times faster than the method sampling Gamma[1,1].

Comment: Instead of doing `Rest - Most`, you can also just call the built-in `Differences` and that's the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I have created an algorithm for uniform random generation over a simplex. You can find the details in the paper in the following link:
    http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610918.2010.551012#.U5q7inJdVNY

Briefly speaking, you can use following recursion formulas to find the random points over the n-dimensional simplex:

*x*<sub>1</sub>=1-*R*<sub>1</sub><sup>1/n-1</sup>

*x*<sub>*k*</sub>=(1-Σ<sub>i=1</sub><sup>*k*</sup>*x*<sub>*i*</sub>)(1-*R*<sub>*k*</sub><sup>1/n-k</sup>), k=2, ..., n-1

*x*<sub>*n*</sub>=1-Σ<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n-1</sup>*x*<sub>*i*</sub>

Where R_i's are random number between 0 and 1.

Now I am trying to make an algorithm to generate random uniform samples from constrained simplex.that is intersection between a simplex and a convex body.

Comment: Do you know how you would alter this algorithm to place more weight on one dimension?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, and I'm late to the party, but this method is much faster than the accepted answer if implemented efficiently.

In Mathematica code:
#/Total[#,{2}]&@Log@RandomReal[{0,1},{n,d}]

In plain English, you generate n rows * d columns of randoms uniformly distributed between 0 and 1.  Then take the Log of everything.  Then normalize each row, dividing each element in the row by the row total.  Now you have n samples uniformly distributed over the (d-1) dimensional simplex.

If found this method here:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33652/uniformly-distributed-n-dimensional-probability-vectors-over-a-simplex

I'll admit, I'm not sure why it works, but it passes every statistical test I can think of.  If anyone has a proof of why this method works, I'd love to see it!