# How to distribute n number of points into a svg polygon javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, geometry

In actual I want to create a 2d styler and I will have place n number of lights in to that. Walls of the home can be polygon and we have to place n lights in that polygon such that each of them are are evenly distributed. Current I did some work work it is not actually working because it is actually consider the enlosing rectangle of the polygon and distributing lights in that.

Here is the example.

```js
function distributePoints(polygon, numberOfPoints) {
    const bounds = getPolygonBounds(polygon);
    const area = polygonArea(polygon);
    const spacing = Math.sqrt(area / numberOfPoints);
    const cols = Math.floor((bounds.maxX - bounds.minX) / spacing);
    const rows = Math.floor((bounds.maxY - bounds.minY) / spacing);
    const distributedPoints = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j <= cols; j++) {
            const point = {
                x: bounds.minX + j * spacing,
                y: bounds.minY + i * spacing,
            };
            if (isPointInPolygon(point, polygon)) {
                distributedPoints.push(point);
            }
        }
    }
    return distributedPoints;
}
function getPolygonBounds(polygon) {
    let minX = Infinity;
    let maxX = -Infinity;
    let minY = Infinity;
    let maxY = -Infinity;
    polygon.points.forEach((point) => {
        if (point.x < minX)
            minX = point.x;
        if (point.x > maxX)
            maxX = point.x;
        if (point.y < minY)
            minY = point.y;
        if (point.y > maxY)
            maxY = point.y;
    });
    return { minX, maxX, minY, maxY };
}
function polygonArea(polygon) {
    let area = 0;
    const { points } = polygon;
    const n = points.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        const j = (i + 1) % n;
        area += points[i].x * points[j].y;
        area -= points[j].x * points[i].y;
    }
    return Math.abs(area / 2.0);
}
function isPointInPolygon(point, polygon) {
    let inside = false;
    const { x, y } = point;
    const { points } = polygon;
    const n = points.length;
    for (let i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n; j = i++) {
        const xi = points[i].x, yi = points[i].y;
        const xj = points[j].x, yj = points[j].y;
        const intersect = yi > y !== yj > y && x < ((xj - xi) * (y - yi)) / (yj - yi) + xi;
        if (intersect)
            inside = !inside;
    }
    return inside;
}
// Generate a random polygon within the bounds of the SVG
function generateRandomPolygon(numberOfVertices, maxX, maxY) {
    const points = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
        points.push({
            x: Math.random() * maxX,
            y: Math.random() * maxY,
        });
    }
    return { points };
}
function generateRandomSimplePolygon(numberOfVertices, maxX, maxY) {
    const points = [];
    // Generate random points
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
        points.push({
            x: Math.random() * maxX,
            y: Math.random() * maxY,
        });
    }
    // Compute the centroid of the points
    const centroid = points.reduce((acc, point) => {
        acc.x += point.x / points.length;
        acc.y += point.y / points.length;
        return acc;
    }, { x: 0, y: 0 });
    // Sort points by angle from centroid to ensure a simple polygon
    points.sort((a, b) => {
        const angleA = Math.atan2(a.y - centroid.y, a.x - centroid.x);
        const angleB = Math.atan2(b.y - centroid.y, b.x - centroid.x);
        return angleA - angleB;
    });
    return { points };
}
const randomPolygon = generateRandomSimplePolygon(30, 700, 700);
const points = distributePoints(randomPolygon, 4);
renderVisualization(randomPolygon, points);
// Render the polygon and points on an SVG element
function renderVisualization(polygon, points) {
    const svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    const svgElement = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "svg");
    svgElement.setAttribute("width", "700");
    svgElement.setAttribute("height", "700");
    svgElement.style.border = "1px solid black";
    // Render the polygon
    const polygonElement = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "polygon");
    polygonElement.setAttribute("points", polygon.points.map((p) => `${p.x},${p.y}`).join(" "));
    polygonElement.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
    polygonElement.setAttribute("fill", "transparent");
    svgElement.appendChild(polygonElement);
    // Render the points
    points.forEach((point) => {
        const pointElement = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "circle");
        pointElement.setAttribute("cx", point.x.toString());
        pointElement.setAttribute("cy", point.y.toString());
        pointElement.setAttribute("r", "3");
        pointElement.setAttribute("fill", "red");
        svgElement.appendChild(pointElement);
    });
    document.body.appendChild(svgElement);
}
```

Comment: It is a bit confusing that you talk about points, lights, walls etc. I know it is the use case but maybe you description could be more clear if you just talk about polygons and circles. So, the circles should be placed inside the polygon? In a pattern or random like the polygon?

Comment: I’m confused, are you talking about wall or ceiling lights? If ceiling lights what is the definition of ‘evenly distributed’?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Algorithm to generate equally distributed points in a polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178414/algorithm-to-generate-equally-distributed-points-in-a-polygon)

Comment: You can't evenly space SVG elements inside a polygon by default unless you do all the calculations yourself. eg. your problem is like the Poisson-Disc Sampling _points that are tightly-packed, but no closer to each other than a specified minimum distance, resulting in a more natural pattern_  https://www.jasondavies.com/poisson-disc/