# how to distribute probability randomly for generating test data in matlab?

Tags: matlab, random, probability

How do I distribute probability randomly over n values in matlab?
If I have 128 vectors.
I want to assign a random probabilty to all of them such that the sum of all of them equals to 1.

e.g.
n=4
p1=0.37
p2=0.21
p3=0
p4=0.42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just divide the vector by the sum of it's elements. For example, for a vector of length 4 you can do:

```
>> v = rand(4, 1);
>> v = v/sum(v)

v = 
    0.2951
    0.3281
    0.0460
    0.3308

>> sum(v)

ans = 

    1.0000
```

Note, I am assuming you want uniformly distributed numbers, since you don't state what distribution you want in the question.

Comment: Can you prove the result is truly uniform? That is the result covers with true distribution all the cases of four numbers that sum up to 1?

Comment: In fact this is false-see deeves'link in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171074/generating-a-probability-distribution?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how random you need to be, [Roger Stafford takes a more stringent approach](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9700-random-vectors-with-fixed-sum/content/randfixedsum.m).